# Oracle SELECT statement in C# returning only first row multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I'm writing a simple select/join statement and it only returns the first row for each of the records I have. I'm not sure if this is a coding error in my C#, or a database error with my tables. Summary is, I want to retrieve all 3 records in my database.

**Oracle Tables:**

-[Oracle Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7ZLk.png)

-[ldhc_accounts table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h7BY.png)

-[donors table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeQFQ.png)

**C# Code:**

```
public List<Donor> Get()
    {
        //Define fields
        List<Donor> donors = new List<Donor>();
        string query;
        OracleCommand cmd;
        OracleDataReader reader;

        query = "SELECT * FROM ldhc_accounts la JOIN donors d ON la.donor_id = d.id";
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Donor d = new Donor();
            {
                d.DonorId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
                d.FName = reader["fname"].ToString();
                d.LName = reader["lname"].ToString();
                d.Address = reader["address"].ToString();
                d.City = reader["city"].ToString();
                d.Province = reader["province"].ToString();
                d.Phone = Convert.ToInt64(reader["phone"]);
                d.LdhcDonorId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["donor_id"]);
                d.TableId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["table_id"]);
                d.DonorCredit = Convert.ToInt64(reader["account_number"]);
                d.DonorCCV = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ccv"]);
                d.DonorExpMonth = Convert.ToInt32(reader["expiry_month"]);
                d.DonorExpYear = Convert.ToInt32(reader["expiry_year"]);
                d.Donor_Amt = Convert.ToInt32(reader["amount"]);
            }

            donors.Add(d);
        }

        conn.Close();

        return donors;
    }
```

**Web Form C#**

```
protected void get_donors_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Donor> d = a_oracle.Get();
        foreach(Donor item in d)
        {
            get_donors.InnerHtml += "<li>"
                + item.DonorId + " " 
                + item.FName + " "
                + item.LName + " "
                + item.Address + " "
                + item.City + " "
                + item.Province + " "
                + item.Phone + " "
                + item.LdhcDonorId + " "
                + item.TableId + " "
                + item.DonorCredit + " "
                + item.DonorCCV + " "
                + item.DonorExpMonth + " "
                + item.DonorExpYear + " "
                + item.Donor_Amt + " "
                + "</li>";
        }
    }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Admin Controls</h1>
        <h2>Select Donor Based on ID</h2>
        <div>Donor ID:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="get_donor_id"></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div><asp:Button runat="server" ID="get_donor_id_btn" OnClick="get_donor_id_btn_Click" Text="Get Donor" /></div>

        <h2>Select All Donors</h2>
        <div><asp:Button runat="server" ID="get_donors_btn" OnClick="get_donors_btn_Click" Text="Get All Donors" /></div>
        <div>
            <ul runat="server" id="get_donors">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <h2>Select Donors based on Amount</h2>

        <h2>Delete a Donor Record</h2>
        Donor ID:<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="del_donor_id"></asp:TextBox>
        <div><asp:Button runat="server" ID="del_btn" OnClick="del_btn_Click" Text="Delete"/></div>
        <div><asp:Label runat="server" ID="del_mssg"></asp:Label></div>
        <h2>Update Donor Information</h2>
    </div>
</form>
```

Final Result:
[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xerPL.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `donors.Add(d)` be outside of the scope of `new Donor()` ?

Comment: I tried that, but it still output the same result. This code was me screwing around with it after.

Comment: Well, put it outside cause it doesn't make sense like this. And put a breakpoint on that line, see if it gets there and the data isn't getting squashed..

Comment: As an FYI: you shouldn't be using `Convert.ToInt32`, `reader` has functions like `reader.GetInt32("fieldName")` for that.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good to know. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or the final HTML?

Comment: @Greggz, Added my breakpoints, counter is adding to my list 3 times. I'm not very good with the debugger - is there anything else I should be looking at?

Comment: @JessicaWong So the problem isn't in the query.  The `donors` list has the whole 3 rows, correct ?

Comment: @JessicaWong What's the `get_donors.InnerHtml` .. a `ul` ?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Wasn't sure if you wanted the final result, or the actual html source code, so I added both

Comment: @Greggz Yes, and yes. The donors list has all 3 rows (I think its in the Screencap). And the `get_donors.InnerHtml` is a `ul`

Comment: Yikes, you really need to be using the [`using()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) keyword around your Disposable objects.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Apologies, pretty new to this.

Comment: @JessicaWong You `List<Donor> d` must only have the 1st row repeated 3 times. Can you verify that ?

Comment: If you really needed to verify the results of the query, you should execute it in Toad or Tora or whatever else Oracle has for running queries.

Comment: Did you try running the query directly against the database? Are you getting duplicate rows there too?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya no dublicates running against db

Comment: @Greggz - So through debugging, (if I'm doing it right) I've found that it is running through each row, (cause I see the new information generated each time) then at `donors.Add(d);`, the previous list item is replaced. So I assume that a new instance (`Donor d = new Donor();`) is fine, but as soon as I hit that `.add` method, everything just gets replaced.

Comment: @JessicaWong How come he is replaced ? If it worked like that `a_oracle.Get()` should have only returned you a `List` with 1 row, no ?

Comment: @greggz sorry, when I mean replace, I mean it just makes each item in the list the current instance of d. So the in the first iteration, it'll return the first row in the list, then the second iteration will replace the first item in the list, and add a second item in the list of itself and so on. So finally the last iteration replaces each item on the list and so on.

Comment: @JessicaWong I really don't get what's happening. Can you isolate the problem ? Like create the `Donors` mannually in a separate project and `.Add(d)` them to the `List<Donor>`. See if the output is the same

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

In my Donor class, my fields were static. Removed the static and everything worked as expected.